# Text file parsing fastest as possible

Tags: python, file, parsing, text

I have a very large file with lines like follows:

....

0.040027 a b c d e 12 34 56 78 90 12 34 56

0.050027 f g h i l 12 34 56 78 90 12 34 56

0.060027 a b c d e 12 34 56 78 90 12 34 56

0.070027 f g h i l 12 34 56 78 90 12 34 56

0.080027 a b c d e 12 34 56 78 90 12 34 56

0.090027 f g h i l 12 34 56 78 90 12 34 56

....

I need to have a dictionary as follows in the fastest way possible.

I using the following code:

```
ascFile = open('C:\\eample.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8')

tag1 = ' a b c d e '

tag2 = ' f g h i l '

tags = [tag1, tag2]

temp = {'k1':[], 'k2':[]}

key_tag = {'k1':tag1, 'k2':tag2 }

t1 = time.time()

for line in ascFile:

    for path, tag in key_tag.items():

        if tag in line:

            columns = line.strip().split(tag, 1)

            temp[path].append([columns[0], columns[-1].replace(' ', '')])

t2 = time.time()

print(t2-t1)
```

I have the following result in 6 second parsing a file of 360MB, I'd like to improve the time.

temp = {'k1':[['0.040027', '1234567890123456'], ['0.060027', '1234567890123456'], ['0.080027', '1234567890123456']], 'k2':[['0.050027', '1234567890123456'], ['0.070027', '1234567890123456'], ['0.090027', '1234567890123456']]
}

Comment: Have you tried storing lists of tuples instead of lists of lists? They should be more lightweight and therefore be created faster.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a fixed number of words in the file that are your keys. Use `split` to break the string, then take a slice of the split list to compute your key directly:

```
import collections

# raw strings don't need \\ for backslash:
FILESPEC = r'C:\example.txt'

lines_by_key = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open(FILESPEC, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        cols = line.split()
        key = ' '.join(cols[1:6])
        pair = (cols[0], ''.join(cols[6:]) # tuple, not list, could be changed
        lines_by_key[key].append(pair)

print(lines_by_key)
```

Comment: THe number of words can change from 0 to 8.I get 6 second in any case

Comment: IN any case I get 6 seconds, to slow for may goal

Answer (score 0):

I used partition instead of split so that the 'in' test and splitting can be done in a single pass.

```
for line in ascFile:

    for path, tag in key_tag.items():

        val0, tag_found, val1 = line.partition(tag)

        if tag_found:
            temp[path].append([val0, val1.replace(' ', '')])
            break
```

Is this any better with your 360MB file?

You might also do a simple test where all you do is loop through the file a line at a time:

```
for line in ascFile:
    pass
```

This will tell you what your best possible time will be.